# Send over 1000 emails per day via gmail, amazon sns, or own smtp

Tags: email, gmail, mail-server, amazon-sns

I'm trying to code a mail sender service. Previously I built a simple desktop application which uses my shared hosting mail server to send html mails. But now it's not enough and I plan switching to Gmail or Amazon SNS.

For Gmail I have to use min 15 different accounts to be able to send up to 1500 emails. Also sometimes gmail blocks the accounts and I have to login and change the passwords.

I've just signed up for Amazon SNS but it does not looks to what I need. You first have to subscribe users then send emails. Also emails are sent from no-reply@sns.amazonaws.com addres. Is this the all service or I can configure it as I wish?

I also read some suggestions to lookup the MX records for the destination mail servers [How to send 1000+ emails per day using an ASP.NET Web site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755772/how-to-send-1000-emails-per-day-using-an-asp-net-web-site/1755805#1755805)

I want a minimum cost solution. So which is best and is there a better solution?

Answer (score 4):

We use Mailjet for 3 sites now. Initially we used the free plan (6000 / month) to test the set-up and reporting. Now the 3 sites are run on it. Very satisfied - especially since they offer dedicated IP monitoring. According to us, it's rather easy to install. SMTP very easy and one of the sites integrates with the API. I'd recommend

Answer (score 3):

There are a multitude of services available for you that will allow you to send 1500+ emails per day and will get the headache of email deliverability off your plate.

- [PostageApp](http://www.postageapp.com/) (Ours!)
- [SendGrid](http://www.sendgrid.com/)
- [Postmark App](http://postmarkapp.com/)
- [Deliver](http://www.deliverhq.com/)
- [Mailjet](http://www.mailjet.com/)

Take a look and see which fit your needs and have the implementation method that you are looking for. They each have a free service, so it's definitely easy to try.

(**Full Disclosure:** I am the Product Manager of PostageApp. Let me know if you have any questions!)

Comment: Mailjet looks good but I'm not sure these services can satisfy my needs. I don't want to spend too much and don't want to configure my server settings (except DNS)

Comment: I think the whole point is that you spend a few hours to fiddle around with your server to make everything work, and they will handle the rest. It's a good time investment up front to reduce resource and time usage later.

Answer (score 1):

A relatively new option for transaction emails that seems pretty good from Mailchimp:

- [Mandrill](http://mandrill.com/)

Looks like it has decent integration with their main service as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize some premium services to [send 1000 emails here](http://www.tutskit.com/send-1000s-emails-using-free-smtp-services/), daily for free

Remember, you should not spam in the services listed, just you create multiple lists in all accounts & send emails daily.